# Is there any papers about learned image features in an unsupervised way?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision

I know that image features produced by pretrained models like VGG-net are the common way to initialize other networks in other tasks. But I was wondering, Is there image features that have been learned in an unsupervised way?

Comment: you can check deep belief networks (a.k.a DBN). network build from layers that were pre-trained by restricted boltzmann machine (a.k.a RBM) (unsupervised)

Comment: @itdxer thank you. I checked them. I was wondering if there is something really good that a lot of other people are using it(produced image features) nowadays? because no one is using DBN and RBM now, Right?